# How to get only those rows where the next row (by datestamp) has a different property in some field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of data like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+----------+
|  o_objguid   |        o_acttime        | o_action |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------+
| 478n8937g990 | 2013-10-02 10:45:33.423 |     1012 |
| 478n8937g990 | 2013-10-02 11:21:57.207 |     1012 |
| 478n8937g990 | 2013-10-02 11:21:57.887 |     1012 |
| 478n8937g990 | 2013-11-15 13:42:11.983 |     1013 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

I want a query to return only those rows where, for a given `o_objguid`, the next row in time sequence does not have an `o_action` of 1012.

I'm using the following query:

```
select d1.* from dbo.dms_audt d1
inner join
(select d2.o_objguid,d2.o_acttime,d2.o_action,
min(datediff(second,d1.o_acttime,d2.o_acttime)) as intervalToNext
from dbo.dms_audt d1
inner join
dbo.dms_audt d2
on
d1.o_objguid=d2.o_objguid
where
d2.o_acttime>d1.o_acttime
group by 
d2.o_objguid,d2.o_acttime,d2.o_action) d2
on
d1.o_objguid=d2.o_objguid
where
datediff(second,d1.o_acttime,d2.o_acttime)=intervalToNext
and
d1.o_action=1012
and
d2.o_action<>1012
```

This query does not return the row with an `o_acttime` of 2013-10-02 10:45:33.423, because the next row has the same `o_action`.  But because I'm using an argument of `second` in the `datediff()` function, the rows with these `o_acttime`:

```
2013-10-02 11:21:57.207
2013-10-02 11:21:57.887
```

are both treated as the same date value for calculation purposes, so both rows are returned, when really the only one that should be returned is the `2013-10-02 11:21:57.887` row.

I tried changing the `datediff()` argument to `millisecond`, but this resulted in an overflow error, probably because a date difference of several days or more will have too many milliseconds to fit in the return type.

I guess I can join the query's results against another query that will use `max(o_acttime)`, so that only the highest `o_acttime` in a group of results that have the same `intervalToNext` will be returned.  But I'm concerned about the size and performance of this query; there are a lot of nested Cartesian products here and it's already pretty slow against a set of 1000000+ rows.  Is there a better way to get the result I want?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as well without computing a CTE twice.  Depending on the data and indexing strategy it may or may not be faster than Joachim's response.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dbo.dms_audt d1
CROSS APPLY ( -- get next action
    SELECT TOP 1
        *
    FROM dbo.tbl_audt X
    WHERE   d1.o_objguid = X.o_objguid
        AND d1.o_acttime < X.o_acttime
    ORDER BY X.o_acttime
) D2
WHERE   D1.o_action = 1012
    AND D2.o_action != 1012
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, SQL Server 2008 does not have `LEAD()` (a 2012 feature) which would have made the query trivial, but you can simulate it using `ROW_NUMBER()`;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o_acttime) rn
  FROM table1
  WHERE o_objguid = '478n8937g990'
)
SELECT a.*
FROM cte a
JOIN cte b
  ON a.rn = b.rn - 1 AND b.o_action <> 1012;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9725d7/1).

Comment: This works by itself.  I'm trying to use it as the second query in a UNION query and getting a `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'` error.  Any idea why?

Comment: @sigil When using a CTE, any previous statement must be ended with a semicolon.  If you are using a UNION as well, all CTEs must be defined before any unions.  e.g.: ;WITH [cte] AS (SELECT 1 [A]) SELECT [A] FROM [cte] UNION ALL SELECT [A]+1 FROM [cte];  -- [cte] was defined once but used twice.